# How to throw a JsonSerializationException when a property is missing in the JSON and not nullable?

Tags: c#, json.net

When deserializing a JSON string with missing properties, those properties in my class are populated with their default values. I want to change the `JsonSerializerSettings` so that, if a property is missing in the JSON and not nullable in the class, an exception is thrown. Conversely, when a property is nullable, it's not required.

I know it's possible with attributes but I want a generic setting.

```cs
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
MyParameters parms = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyParameters>(json, settings);
```

Example:

```cs
public class MyParameters
{
    public string Message1 { get; set; }
    public string Message2 { get; set; }
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
    public int? MyNullableInt { get; set; }
}
```

The following JSON should be deserializable:

```
{
    "Message1": "A message",
    "MyInt ": 1
}
```

As result:

```
Message1 = "A message"
Message2 = null
MyInt = 1
MyNullableInt = null
```

But the following JSON should cause an exception because `MyInt` is missing:

```
{
    "Message1": "A message",
    "MyNullableInt": 1
}
```

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen That's not what I'm asking, I explicit said that I don't want to use attributes +  when an property is nullable, I dont want it to be required so I can't use `settings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;`

Comment: MissingMemberHandling only works if you have a property in the json that doesn't exist on your type, not for your case. As far as I know, other than the required attribute, there is no other way of handling this. Let me rephrase that. All the ways I know how to handle this case involves changing the type you deserialize into. You don't want to do that so then I think you're out of luck. Hopefully someone will prove me wrong.

Comment: Can you simply decorate `MyInt` with: `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]`? The base converter will throw when that property is not part of the JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom [`ContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm) to do what you want:

```
class NonNullablePropertiesRequiredResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty prop = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        Type propType = prop.PropertyType;
        if (propType.IsValueType && !(propType.IsGenericType && propType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)))
        {
            prop.Required = Required.Always;
        }
        return prop;
    }
}
```

Apply the resolver to your `JsonSerializerSettings` like this when you deserialize:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.ContractResolver = new NonNullablePropertiesRequiredResolver();
MyParameters parms = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyParameters>(json, settings);
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/t56U2a